# ConstraintLayout match parent height on larger screens but scroll on smaller

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have created layout like this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="top"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="middle"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It does scroll on small screens as expected.
But on larger screens it leaves space below
[image]

How can I make layout match screen height, but still be scrollable on small screens?

Tried to set 'middle' height to 0dp, but this did not help.

Adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to `ScrollView` and set middle's height to `0dp` solves the problem with space, but brings problem with scrolling - on small screens middle is shrinking, instead of scrolling.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Set the height of the middle `TextView` to `0dp` (to match constraints) to fill the available space and add `android:fillViewport="true"` attribute to your `ScrollView` to stretch its content to fill the viewport.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="top"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/middle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="middle"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="300dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have updated the post. In short - it does solve problem with space, but bring problem with scrolling.

Comment: Updated my answer. Change `android:minHeight="300dp"` to `app:layout_constraintHeight_min="300dp"`.

Comment: Thanks for this, had the same problem as OP and your answer really helped me. Was really astounded to find out that with the ConstraintLayout you can achieve the desired effect without any coding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `app:layout_constraintHeight_min` instead of `android:minHeight`

So this layout is correct

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="top"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/middle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="middle"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/middle" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```